# How to return the namespace path of a property in an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that "resolves" the dot delimited path of a nested property in an object.

So say you have the following object:

```
var obj = {
    A: {
        A_1: {
        },
        A_2: {
            A_2_a: {},
            A_2_b: {
                A_2_b_1: {},
                A_2_b_2: {},
            }
        },
        A_3: {},
    },
    B: {
        B_1: {
        },
        B_2: {
            B_2_a: {
            },
            B_2_b: {
                B_2_b_1: {},
                B_2_b_2: {},
            }
        },
        B_3: {},
    },
};
```

I want to call a function on the object like `resolve(obj, "B_2_b_2")` and have it return the full object path to the property, ie: `B.B_2.B_2_b.B_2_b_2`.

Comment: What if the same property name is present twice in `obj`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you post one or two of your best "failed attempts"?

Comment: Or, you just want to split by an underscore?

Comment: Please edit your question to put your sample code instead of "tried a lot" (removed from the question as unrelated).

Comment: I've created a script that essentially does this: https://github.com/ajcrites/json-visualize/blob/master/src/JsonVisualize.js -- as you can see it's not the simplest thing, so maybe you should ask a more specific question

Comment: Are you wanting to return the *string* `B.B_2.B_2_b.B_2_b_2`, or the *value of the property* `B.B_2.B_2_b.B_2_b_2`?

Comment: I want to return the string. I don't know how I could make the question any more "specific".

Comment: I don't have much to show because I've been trying things and upon finding they don't work deleting them and starting over. Also the method is part of a large library I'm writing so much of it would be confusing to view due to all the calls made to other methods in the lib.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a naming convention, like in your example object:

```
function resolve(id) {
    var parts = id.split("_");
    var path = [];
    for (var i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
        path.push(parts.slice(0, i+1).join("_"));
    return path;
}

> resolve("B_2_b_2")
["B", "B_2", "B_2_b", "B_2_b_2"]
> resolve("B_2_b_2").join(".")
"B.B_2.B_2_b.B_2_b_2"
```

With the path array you can easily recurse over your nested object to get the property values.

---

A tree search in a data object is trivial. However, we can optimize that by assuming a naming convention:

```
function resolve(obj, id) {
    if (id in obj)
        return [id]; // we've found it
    var path;
    for (var l=id.length-1; l>0; l--) {
        var sub = id.substr(0, l);
        if (sub in obj && (path = resolve(obj[sub], id))) {
            path.unshift(sub);
            return path;
        }
    }
    for (var prop in obj) {
       if (path = resolve(obj[prop], id)) {
            path.unshift(prop);
            return path;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. So basically make an array of the path first and then while iterating over the object while doing a search I would just look for a hasOwnProperty match? Hmm.. You may be onto something. I'm going to try.

Comment: Wait no, see that won't work: That would assume the path of a property will maintain a given naming convention. That is not the case of my intentions.

Comment: You don't have a naming convention? So what do you look for then? Without that, a property name might occur anywhere (and multiple times) in the object.

Comment: if a property name occurred multiple times then I would return the path to the first found instance of that property name.

Comment: You know that object keys are not ordered, so the function might return different results for the same object?

Comment: Yep, the solution is to first build a "paths map" object. See my solution.

Comment: @Xaxis: Yeah, that would be a tree search with caching. However, did you notice my edit? It will be much more efficient with my solution

Comment: Yes your solution would be more efficient. The reason I'm keeping the methods separate in my solution is because I decided I wanted to have a separate method just for returning all the paths of a given object. Thanks so much for helping out with this!

Answer (score 1):

Eureka! I figured it out! The below answer is in the form of a library I'm writing but it should be relatively easy to follow.

As it turns out, the best course of action (as far as I can tell) is to first using a separate function, build an object from the target object containing all the property paths:

```
/**
 * Returns an object containing all of the property paths of an object. Each
 * property path is referenced by the property name.
 * @param {object} The object to target
 * @return {object} Object containing paths ELSE undefined
 */
paths: function( obj, path, lastKey, nextKey ) {
    var o, key,
        path = path ? path : {},
        lastKey = lastKey ? lastKey : "",
        nextKey = nextKey ? nextKey : "";

    for ( o in obj ) {      

        // Push path onto stack
        path[o] = (nextKey + "." + lastKey + "." + o).replace(/^[.]+/g, "");

        // Pass updated "nextKey" along with next recurse
        key = nextKey + "." + lastKey;

        // Call again on all nested objects
        if ( (lib).isPlainObject(obj[o]) ) {
            (lib).paths(obj[o], path, o, key);
        }
    }

    return (lib).len(path) ? path : undefined;
},
```

Then we use the resolve method as a "wrapper" to the paths method, returning the targeted property key's namespace.

```
resolve: function( obj, key ) {     
    return (lib).paths(obj)[key];
},
```

Using the object I posted originally above:

```
var res = o.resolve(obj, "A_2_b_1");
// Returns "A.A_2.A_2_b.A_2_b_1"
```

Just for reference, the `paths` method returns an object that looks something like this:

```
// {
    // A: [...]
    // A_1: [...]
    // A_2: [...]
    // A_2_a: [...]
    // A_2_b: [...]
    // A_2_b_1: [
    //  0: "A_2_b_1"
    //  1: "A.A_2.A_2_b.A_2_b_1"
    // ]
    // A_2_b_2: [...]
    // A_2_c: [...]
    // A_3: [...]
    // B: [...]
    // ...
// }
```

Where each property maps to its path in the object.

Comment: Please, change your `resolve` method to a simple `return lib.paths(obj)[key];` and remove the key from the arrays. Btw, building a whole `paths` object just to lookup one path is very inefficient

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for the advice! I tend to write things in a more explanatory way when I'm trying to solve a problem. Then I refactor. But you're absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding efficiency: in the library implementation the paths for a given object will only be computed one time and methods in the chain will have access to that data.